# How to rename a field when get distinct values with PHP and MongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb, distinct, php-5.6

My environment is php5.6, MongoDB 4.0.13 and mongo driver 1.6.16, and supposed I have collection/table `table_x` from  database `db_x` as below:

```
    code_x   code_y      value        name   color
   ------------------------------------------------
1   00001    111         300           aa     1 
2   00001    222         100           bb     3
3   00002    111         200           cc     1
4   00002    444         400           dd     2
.....
99  00029    222         200           ee     3
100 00030    999         400           ff     1
```

I would like to get the distinct `code_y` values, and I use below code, the output is equal to `select distinct code_y from table_x`:

```
$res = $db_x->command(array("distinct"=>"table_x", "key"=>"code_y"));

foreach ($res['values'] as $idx) {
    $res[$idx]['_id'] = $idx;
}
```

but my expected output is below SQL query
`select distinct code_y as dept from table_x`

Comment: Why do you need to do that? distinct returns an array of values

Comment: Can I convert that single array values to different array value?

Comment: Not with distinct. You can achieve the same using aggregate group and project

Comment: hi, I already tried, but project not works, and it needs cursor, I got dirty results, and not what i need, could you please show me same sample code? Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I use the below code to get renamed fields.

```
$res = $db_x->command (
        array(
            "aggregate" => "table_x",
            "pipeline" =>
                array(
                    array( '$group' => array( "_id" => ['new_id' =>'$code_y', 'new_name' => '$code_x', 'new_color' => '$color']))),
            "cursor" => ['batchSize' => 200]
        )
);
```